# TeamCity/Maven DONT make modules be 'SKIPPED'

Tags: maven, teamcity

Lets say I've a root project called R. And it has modules A, B, C and D as submodules but each is an application.

Whenever I use teamcity/maven and there is an error it skips other modules whether its a compile/test.

So,
Whenever compiling it shows

```
R................SUCCESS
A................SUCCESS
B................FAILURE
C................SKIPPED
D................SKIPPED
```

And I want to see results in both C and D. How can I achieve this using teamcity/maven. Is there any parameter?

Comment: try run  `mvn clean install -fn ` please

Comment: I would recommend to use `mvn --fail-at-end ..` instead...

Comment: @khmarbaise if you post that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @khmarbaise  and how can I pass this to teamcity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option must be used carefully, but can be useful. The build never fails, regardless of the project result. All failures are ignore, the build just continues. On your project:

```
mvn clean install --fail-never (or just --fn)

[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Module A .............................................. SUCCESS [2.583s]
[INFO] Module B .............................................. SUCCESS [0.086s]
[INFO] Module C .............................................. FAILED [1.598s]
[INFO] Module D .............................................. SUCCESS [0.051s]
[INFO] Reactor ............................................... SUCCESS [0.921s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error for project: Module C (during install)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.

Please refer to /Users/clement/workspaces/experiments/Project/module-C/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  + Ignoring failures
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sun May 09 10:43:41 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/79M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Module C failed, D is not skipped, and the global build is successful.

After that in the Teamcity you can add [build failure condition](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Failure+Conditions) for checking the results and failed the build if found any errors

Comment: I still want to keep the failures and see them at result. I just dont want SKIPPED tests. If modules are dependant, they can fail

Comment: I see, for this reason I said  `add [build failure condition](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Failure+Conditions)`. The condition will check does logs has an error.

Comment: Where do I put --fail-never in TeamCity?

Comment: if your build has `Maven runner step` you can edit the step and add this option of `Additional Maven command line parameters`.  [the step example](https://automated-testing.info/uploads/default/original/2X/0/020c7feb6bc0d3fdf35113d678b5e619f21df07b.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `mvn --fail-at-end` all modules will be gone through but the failure will be shows only at the end of the build.

Comment: Where do I put these parameters in teamcity?

Comment: Or put it in project's pom.xml?

Comment: In the command line of Maven...No they can't be put into the `pom.xml`..

Comment: Do you know how can I put that into TeamCity?